# Reading in 16 bits from a 32 bit register

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, arm

I'm trying to read certain values from a particular register. The manual specifies that I must access the 16-bit LSB access first and 16-bit MSB access next. Do I just read in all 32 bits at once and then mask the remaining 16 msb/lsb respectively as needed? Or would there be a way to read only 16 bits fist.

Thanks, 
Neco

Comment: It would help us if you specified what processor you are talking about.

Comment: What architecture are you working on? Which register?

Comment: The register in question is a 'time counter' on a SoC

Comment: You should specify the SOC part - in general registers are specific to a controller, not a processor.  To understand how to correctly access a hardware register precise details are necessary.  Without those, everything is guesswork.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the manual says to first access the 16-bit LSB  and then the 16-bit MSB, do as the manual says.

For example (little endian):

```
#define REG (*(volatile uint32_t *) 0x1234)

uint16_t val_hi, val_lo;

val_lo = *((volatile uint16_t *) &REG);
val_hi = *((volatile uint16_t *) &REG + 1);
```

Note that compilers also sometimes provide HI and LO identifiers to access LSB or MSB, like in addition to `REG` in the example:

```
#define REGL (*(volatile uint16_t *) 0x1234)
#define REGH (*(volatile uint16_t *) 0x1236)
```

Comment: However, this doesn't guarantee "atomicity" in the sense that the register may change in-between reading lo and hi.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth the manual requires the access of the 32-bit register to be non-atomic: first the 16-bit LSB then the 16-bit MSB. This is not an unusal requirement. What this code doesn't guarantee is the atomic access of the two 16-bit reads. Embedded compilers are usually pretty conservative regarding access of volatile objects, but if any doubt assembly code can be used.

Comment: Reading the low 16bit may transfer the high 16 bits to an register. Maybe the doc tells it or not ;-)

Comment: @ouah: Ah, yes, I missed that specification.  Then +1!

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what language you are using to do this. I will assume you are using inline assembly in C.

I am most familiar with NASM. Using NASM syntax for i386:

```
mov eax, 0x12345678 ; load whatever value
mov bx, ax          ; put LSW in bx
shr eax, 16         ; shift MSW to ax
                    ; now ax = MSW, bx = LSW
```

I'm guessing the gas (C) code would be something like this:

```
movl $0x12345678, %eax # load whatever value
movw %ax, %bx          # put LSW in bx
shrl $16, %eax         # shift MSW to ax
                       # now ax = MSW, bx = LSW
```